# How do I configure Tomcat 7 running on an EC2 instance to respond on the main URL, not a subdirectory?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I finally got a simple grails app deployed and running on AWS EC2 instance with Tomcat7. How do I configure Apache and/or Tomcat so the app would be accessible from the following URL:

```
http://107.20.253.141/
```

as opposed to how I have to access it now at:

```
http://107.20.253.141/Grails2Test-0.1/
```

I didn't have to specify port 8080 either so the two are working together nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way:  Rename the directory within `webapps` (or the `.war` file) to `ROOT` (or `ROOT.war` if you're deploying a `.war`), replacing the default webapp.

Less simple, more flexible: add a `<Context>` configuration to `server.xml` to map a webapp to root - set the `docBase` to your webapp's location and the `path` to an empty string, `""`.